# Android app is unable to launch on device

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, nullpointerexception, google-cloud-messaging

i am developing an app in android and there is no syntax error but when i deploy my app on my device it gives following logcat errors please help me if any one can i am doing my colg project

**These are the following logcat errors**

```
            12-01 01:52:10.310: E/Trace(7853): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
            12-01 01:52:10.310: D/ActivityThread(7853): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
            12-01 01:52:10.310: D/ActivityThread(7853): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
            12-01 01:52:10.310: D/ActivityThread(7853): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
            12-01 01:52:10.380: W/dalvikvm(7853): Refusing to reopen boot DEX '/system/framework/hwframework.jar'
            12-01 01:52:10.660: I/ActivityThread(7853): Pub com.aiou.fyp.provider: com.aiou.fyp.DataProvider
            12-01 01:52:11.070: W/dalvikvm(7853): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42022438)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aiou.fyp/com.aiou.fyp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2077)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2102)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4838)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:874)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at com.aiou.fyp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5010)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2041)
            12-01 01:52:11.090: E/AndroidRuntime(7853):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: share the code where you are getting this exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this usually happens when you forgot to inflate one of your layout components but you are trying to use it in your class.

Comment: i didn't got u brother could u just give me some example to understand U

Comment: well, you will have to share your code with us so we can see what is missing.